# Random colors in html via node.js

Tags: javascript, html

```
function getRandomColor() {
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
   var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
}
return color;
}
```

I am trying to use the code above to output random colors in the html code below
As in that it should alter the color in the html code below, and I am having trouble linking the two files so the js file can alter the html file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ten Random Colors</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li style="color: #ae3d04">ae3d04</li>
<li style="color: #ce8cfc">ce8cfc</li>
<li style="color: #510f40">510f40</li>
<li style="color: #a256c6">a256c6</li>
<li style="color: #d85fd1">d85fd1</li>

  ... 100 list items in total
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

this is what i am being asked to do:

> Each time you run the program it should generate a different set of
>   color values. The color values should be generated as 6 equally likely
>   hexadecimal digits, which means they should appear with the same
>   probability. For the purpose of this assignment, you can assume that
>   the floating point numbers produced by Math.random() are equally
>   likely numbers between 0.0 and 1.0.
>
> Send the output to the console by calling console.log. You can view
>   the HTML document that you generate by redirecting standard output to
>   a file as follows.
>
> use this command in node.js cmd
>
> ```
> node colors.js > colors.html
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your node server code? Or do you actually want to do this client side?

Comment: btw, you can get a random color in one line with `'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);` ([source](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/)).

Comment: this is what i am being asked to do

Comment: @vrmc: Except that might produce too short strings. The OP's solution is much better.

Comment: @ashrafdauodi: You seem to be expected to do a simple `console.log`ging to stdout. You're not supposed to write a complete html file, nor are your supposed to set up a node server.

Comment: @Bergi I thought that too but the command node colors.js > colors.html confuses me

Comment: @ashrafdauodi: That's just a [redirection of the stdout to a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) so that you can view it elsewhere - I guess you're invoking this remotely?

Comment: @Bergi I understand what it wants but how do i output a proper html file

Comment: I'm not sure whether it even wants you to output html, or only view your output "as html in the browser". If the former, you probably should just go with `console.log("<!doctype html><html>…")`.

Comment: @Bergi oh, right. You're totally right. Of course it's not important but the idea of building up a base-16 number digit-by-digit makes me mental. There are better solutions in the comments of the article I linked to.